# Как поменять иконку Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Надо поменять иконку Tkinera на свою, но так чтобы при превращении из .py в .exe иконка была и на других компьютерах. Все способы, которые нашёл в интернете не помогают, т.к. при переносе программы с ноута на пк она перестаёт работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap(r'icon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пишет ошибку: _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "lib.ico" not defined.
Если вписать полный путь, то при преобразовании .py в .exe работать ничего не будет(пробовал уже)

Comment: @DGDays https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176638/tkinter-tclerror-error-reading-bitmap-file

Comment: Новая ошибка:  _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "lib.ico": no such file or directory.

Comment: Он почему-то не может найти файл в директории, но в какую именно директорию надо закинуть иконку я не знаю.

Comment: @DGDays В одну папку с файлом питона(или исполняемым)

Comment: Уже нашел решение. Там команда большая и непонятная мне, но если иконка в одной папке с кодом, то все работает на ура